# How to Redirect Page After Session Time Out in ASP.Net c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I tried this stuff but redirect is not working ......

```
  `<sessionState timeout="60"></sessionState>
        <authentication mode="Forms">
          <forms defaultUrl="login.aspx"
              loginUrl="login.aspx"
              slidingExpiration="true"
              timeout="60" />
        </authentication>`
```

my asp code

````
    ```
    void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)   
       {  
           // Code that runs when a new session is started  
           if (Session["LoginUserName"] != null)  
           {  
           //Redirect to Welcome Page if Session is not null  
               Response.Redirect("Welcome.aspx");  

           }  
           else  
           {  
           //Redirect to Login Page if Session is null & Expires   
               Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");  

           }
````

welcome.aspx and login.aspx are webforms

Comment: 1) In your configuration timeout=60 which means 60  minutes
2) And redirect is not working means you did tried debug and your Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");  run but not redirected ??

Comment: yes this is  what happened

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Session_Start isn't the right place to put redirects.
In Welcome.aspx, put this logic:

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
   base.OnInit(e);
   if (!Request.IsAuthenticated)
   {
      FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage();
      HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
   }
}
```

In Login.aspx:

```
protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (ValidateUser())
      FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(Username.Text, true);
}

private bool ValidateUser()
{
   // put here your user validation logic
}
```

Please note: this is very trivial way of authentication, useful if you need to implement your own validation logic; you'll probably want to checkout Membership ( https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/previous-versions/aspnet/yh26yfzy(v=vs.100) ), possibly with SqlMembershipProvider, or even better ASP.Net Identity: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/.